# Ember.js: How to load audio-files

Tags: rest, express, ember.js

I'm developing an ember-app which must load an audio file at some point. Since I'm developing the REST-Server (express.js) in parallel, I'm wondering how to provide the mp3-file and how to deal with it on the ember-side.

So: How can I load an audio-file as part of my model?
(Maybe I should just store an URL in my model?)

Comment: I would just store an URI or an id, or just access the audio file with the models `id`. And then probably just create an `<audio>` tag to play it.

Comment: Try an Ember addon like http://sethbrasile.github.io/ember-audio/

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use the audio element, you can do what you suggest, and include a URL. There are probably safestring concerns, and you'll have to plan for multiple audio types.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const thisData = [ // example of some data
  {
    id: 1,
    audioUrl: 'http://sheriffderek.consulting/resources/audio/spicy.mp3'
  }
];

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return thisData;
  }
});
```

...

```
{{#each content as |sound|}}
  <audio controls>
    <source src="{{sound.audioUrl}}" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
  </audio>
{{/each}}
```

### Here's a test:

https://ember-twiddle.com/fdcdc741f67aa8603d276229a907d5e9?openFiles=routes.application.js%2C

audio tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video

I'm not sure what happens if there are many on one page... when I use soundcloud or something, I need a service to keep track of what is playing and what shouldn't be.